# How can I make a method with lambda parameter?

Tags: c#, generics, lambda

I have some classes (T1, T2, T3). The only difference between them is the amount of properties. Every property is set with the help of Generator which determines every property as a random number from Distribution (normal, exponential, etc..)
I need to implement methods 'For' and 'Set' so this code works:

```
var generator = new Generator<T2>()
    .For(z => z.A)
    .Set(newDistribution)
    .For(z => z.B)
    .Set(anotherNewDistribution);
```

**ALSO** For() after For() should be impossible:

```
generator.For(z => z.A).For(z => z.B).Set(d) ← is not valid!
```

This is what I tried:

```
public class Generator<T>
{
    public T generatedClass;
    public T Generate(Random rnd)
    {
     ...........
    }

    public double For(Func<T, double> func)
    {
        return func(generatedClass);
    }
}
```

But what should I do next? Make an extension method for double? But it won't work because an extension method can not be generic.

Comment: What makes you think an extension method can't be generic?  What error do you get when writing a generic extension method?

Comment: "Extension method must be defined in non-generic static class" says Visual Studio.

Comment: Yes, that error correctly tells you why you can't have an extension method in a generic class.  You stated that you can't have a generic *method* be an extension method, and you won't get that error by having a generic method be an extension method.

Comment: @Servy Yes, but I need to have a property `public static Generator<T> parent` so that I can tell my Generator that one of the fields is changed. Also, `Set()` method has to return Generator<T> so that I can call method `For` after it. That's why I need my extension class to be generic.

Comment: And why does the extension method need to be in the same class as that property?

Comment: @Servy now I am confused :( Because otherwise I would not be able to inform that property that one of the fields is changed. Am I missing something? Would you be so kind and show me in code what you mean?

Comment: Why do you think you can do that with the extension method in one class and not when it's in another?